# Music piece only in Blues scale & Static Harmony

Tags: notation, jazz, time-signatures, blues, genre

I have been stuck in one of my music compostion. It hasn't been completed for a long time cause I can't realise what's gonna on in the harmony below. The song is based only on Blues scale, so my questions are:

1. Has this song a static harmony in C and blues scale or is it just my opinion what harmony changes I want to have?
2. Is there just a one music piece that's played only in blues scale?
3. (Is it ok to just put N.C. chord symbol in the beginning? - this answer doesnt completely cover my misunderstanding)
4. What genre is exactly this piece? I find it jazzy blues shuffle.
5. Any better reason to have different time signature?

Thank you very much for any good ideas or answers.

***Intro:***
[image: music part]

**EDIT:**
Posting another piece after the intro would help to answer, I think.

***After Intro:***
[image]

Comment: I don't understand why you would put NC above a line that clearly has the following chords: Cm, Eb, F5, Gbsus4.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - NC denotes no chord should be played at that time. Usually there will be a chord or two that will fit, but with NC none of them will be played. Since it's blues, the first chord could easily be C7.

Comment: What particular instrument do you have in mind to play the lead line?

Comment: @Tim it is only piano part that is all and thanks and C7 doesnt sound good. could it be written in C minor?

Comment: @ToddWilcox thanks i think thats it, now I can see that it is song played on blues scale but the progresion seems to be no-bluesy. Now i do not think it's a pure blues

Comment: Perhaps it could be thought of as a minor blues. The Gb is only a passing note, so isn't that significant, especially over an F chord, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a blues shuffle. As such, a time sig. of 4/4 would be fine, with the triplets note at the top. This sort of brings it into the 12/8 feel, without using semis - quavers will suffice.

Because it's the blues, it would probably use C7 and Eb so far. The resolving leading note doesn't feature too much in blues - why should it! That harmony change has been used many, many times. The Gb and Bb both belong in the C minor blues scale notes, so no problems there either. This sort of stuff cannot be analysed in a classical theory way.

Yes, it needs N.C. where there is no chord, to indicate that the lead player is playing out by himself. At some point, however, a chord needs to be present - not shown on the examples.

It's a little repetitious, but being blues, it's almost a given...

Other chords you'd probably use are F7, G7 and Bb for starters, and cadences don't need to be present like in serious music; this breaks a lot of those 'rules' - which aren't law anyway!